# Sorting image-files based on size using bubble sort (or other algorithm) inside a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, matplotlib, bubble-sort

I need some help to sort all files (images) that are inside a folder based on file-size. Trying to use bubble sort algorithm but cannot get it to work.

```
 import os

def order(x, y):    
    if x[1] < y[1]:
        return x, y
    else:
        return y, x

def bubble(my_dict):
    d_items = my_dict.items()
    for j in range(len(d_items) - 1):
        for i in range(len(d_items) - 1):
            d_items[i], d_items[i+1] = order(d_items[i], d_items[i+1])
    return d_items


my_dir = './images'
my_dict = {} # declaring empty dictionary

for f in os.listdir(my_dir):
    path = os.path.join(my_dir, f)
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        my_dict[os.path.basename(path)] = os.path.getsize(path)



sorted_tuples = bubble(my_dict)
print(sorted_tuples)
```

`my_dict` is a dictionary but i get this error when i use this code:

**What i need:**
compare execution time with bubble sort and another sorting algorithm. When sorting different numbers of items (first 100 files, then 300 files, then 500 files, ... until 2300 files) i need to plot this into matplotlib and compare those two algorithm execution times.

As you can see i am stuck on just make bubble sort working.

Comment: I suggest you debug your sorting with a mocked dictionary, e.g., `my_dict = {'a': 42, 'b': 12, 'c': 20}`. Add entries as desired.

Answer (score 1):

`my_dict.items()` is a iterator, you can only iterate it once. Convert it to a list first:

```
def bubble(my_dict):
    d_items = list(my_dict.items())
    for j in range(len(d_items) - 1):
        for i in range(len(d_items) - 1):
            d_items[i], d_items[i+1] = order(d_items[i], d_items[i+1])
    return d_items

sorted_tuples = bubble(my_dict)
```

Also, it's worth mentioning that Python has internal sort function as well:

```
sorted_tuples = sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[::-1])
```